# If a sequence converges to an irrational number, prove that different sets of the sequences are not bounded.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Sorry for the oddly worded title. The original was too long, so I had to try and shorten it as best as I could.

Here is the question:

Let $a∈(0, 1)$ be an irrational number and suppose there exists a sequence

$r_n = \frac {p_n} {q_n}$ with
$p_n$, $q_n ∈  \Bbb N$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} r_n = a$.

Show that both $\{p_n : n ∈ N \}$ and $\{q_n : n ∈ N \}$ are not bounded

Suppose $a∉\Bbb Q, a∈(0, 1),$ and sequence $r_n = \frac {p_n} {q_n} \to a$, with $p_n, q_n∈ \Bbb N$. Show that both $\{p_n:n∈\Bbb N\}, \{q_n:n∈\Bbb N\}$ are not bounded.

I'm pretty confused by the question. I'm not sure where to begin. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $\{p_n\}$ is bounded.

If $\{q_n\}$ is also bounded, then the set $\{\frac{p_n}{q_m} \mid n,m \in \Bbb N\} \subset \Bbb Q$ is finite, thus it cannot have an irrational limit point.

So $\{q_n\}$ must be unbounded. But then, there exists a subsequence $q_{n_k} \to \infty$. Thus $\frac{p_{n_k}}{q_{n_k}}\to 0$, which contradicts $a \in (0,1)$.

If you suppose first that $\{q_n\}$ is bounded, you'll get the same contradictions with $\frac{q_n}{p_n} \to \frac{1}{a}$.

Comment: I'm confused about the end. If q_n is bounded and p_n is not, wouldn't the limit go to infinity? @Nitrogen

Comment: @eulersnumber Yes, of course.  But that's also a contradiction since no converging sequence can have a subsequence with limit $\infty$.

Comment: Rad. Thanks! I guess I am confused about how if {q_n} is bounded that that implies q/p --> 1/a.